# Hey guys I jut wanted to debug a recent project, but when I tried it, I got an error

Tags: flutter, dart

Launching lib\main.dart on ASUS I005DA in debug mode...  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:detachedConfiguration1'.    > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:?.

Launching lib\main.dart on ASUS I005DA in debug mode...  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:detachedConfiguration1'.    > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:?.